# include nav-menu js

Tags: javascript, include

Помогите, испробовал уже несколько кодов и никак не могу подобрать необходимый. Возможности подключить php нет, но находил коды по js, что это возможно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В header-nav находится класс хедера с навигацией, его нужно подключить через include-nav.js
Ну а вывод через скрипт я уже добавил. Инклуд только непонятно как сделать
Сайт будет многостраничный и менять этот кусок кода не хочется по сто раз

Ну или возможно как-то добавить хедер с другими дивами и прочим в js, чтобы не инклудить ? У меня просто ошибку выбивает, пишет 9+ и горит красным
Спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно кому-то пригодится готовый ответ, поэсперементировал и получил то, что мне надо :)
А этот файл подключаем вместо хедера как обычный скрипт (именно на месте хедера, не ниже, ни выше)